# Chromatic index of planar 4-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Planar graphs of max degree 4 are, in general, not necessarily edge-4-colorable.  However, what is the situation if the graph is 4-regular, is it edge-4-colorable?  I am guessing this is known ... what might be a reference for the answer to this question?

And what is the situation if we require that no two triangles share an edge (although they can share a vertex)?

Answer (score 2):

The following graph, taken from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2490130) (and originally from the paper [On the Existence of a Perfect Matching for 4-Regular Graphs Derived from Quadrilateral Meshes](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3797/6a5edbc1002551ee23576186115c2faab7e0.pdf) by Carbonera and Shepherd), is a counterexample:

[image]

This is a planar $4$-regular graph which does not have a perfect matching: deleting the central vertices leaves four odd components. But in any $4$-coloring of the edges, all the color classes would need to be perfect matchings.

If you add the additional constraint that no two triangle faces share an edge, then we can still use essentially the same counterexample. Replace each of the fragments $C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4$ by the following:

[image]

This is a $13$-vertex graph in which all vertices except the two highlighted ones have degree $4$, and no two triangles share an edge. Connect the two highlighted vertices to the center $S$ in the same way, and you get another $4$-regular graph with no perfect matching.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: What is the situation if there are no triangles sharing an edge?  Is this known? I will edit the question to include this as a subquestion.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that you sent an answer to the subquestion, but it seems to have disappeared ... could you post it again please?

Comment: I deleted it because it contained a mistake.

Comment: Ok, thank you again ...

Comment: I've edited my answer to deal with this case as well.

Comment: Thank you, very beautiful.  I have one more modification in mind, but I need to think about it a bit more ... I will post as I resolve the issue.

Comment: Quick question, as you might already know the answer before I start out to check; the chromatic number of this example is 4, correct?  Not 3?  Apologies for being slow.

Comment: Apparently it is 3 ... correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: The chromatic number is $4$.

Comment: Thanks! I got it wrong somewhere ...

Comment: Ok, I will have to check this with a computer ... you can color the fragments with 3 colors, and get the same two colors always at the red vertices, so you just use the third color for the vertices in S ... or what am I getting wrong?

Comment: The fragments are also not individually 3-colorable.

Comment: No, I did not mean that, I meant that in each fragment, you can color one of the highlighted vertices with red, say, and the other one with green, and do the same in all fragments.  You can actually color each fragment so that this is so ... does this make sense now?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I made a silly mistake ... thanks, and apologies for this ... I should have done it on paper rather than trying to do it in my head.  Ok, I hope to post a modification just yet, but as I said, I need to think about it.