# 4- regular triangle free connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I know that there exists a $4$-regular connected graph with even number of vertices that does not have a perfect matching ( an example of this graph is stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488017/k-regular-k-2-edge-connected-graph-with-even-number-of-vertices-and-no-per))

I want to know if there is a $4$-regular triangle free connected graph with even number of vertices that does not have a perfect matching? or if not, how can I prove it by Tutte's theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the example you linked can be modified to be triangle free and still be $4$-regular, have an even number of vertices, and have no perfect matching. 
Just replace each component $Ci$ with a $4$-regular graph with large girth and odd number of vertices.
The total number of vertices will be $2 + 4\cdot \#V(C1)$ which is even,
and the graph has no perfect matching by the same argument.

Edit: To be more specific, you could take each of the components $C1,\ldots,C4$ to be this graph:
[image: 4-regular graph with 11 vertices and girth 4]
This graph has 11 vertices and is triangle free, since the shortest cycles have length 4.

In general, the *girth* of a graph means the minimal length of a cycle.
There exist $4$-regular graphs with arbitrarily large girth $g$.
The ones with fewest possible vertices are known as [$(4,g)$ cage graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cage_(graph_theory)).
We can generalize the example above by  choosing each $Ci$ to be a $(4,g)$ cage graph with an odd number of vertices, e.g. 
the [Robertson graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson_graph),
but with one edge ''broken up'' to connect to the vertices in the middle component $S$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please explain more about what do you mean of large girth? could you please draw one of the $c_i$'s?

Comment: Sure no problem, please see the edits above.

Comment: I tried a lot of graphs but this is very good, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! This was more complicated than I thought initially, because of the condition that C1 has an odd number of vertices. It is not clear to me how to construct (4,g) cage graphs in general, but I'm guessing the construction can be adapted somehow for this condition.